# Django template variable value to string literal comparison fails

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following code in my template that supposed to compare the value of `watchinstance.shift`, which can be either "DAY" or "NIGHT", to a literal string "DAY". The comparisson always fails.

```
{% for watchinstance in watchinstance_list %}
    {% if watchinstance.shift == "DAY" %}
        <p>shift is DAY</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Using `ifequal` doesn't work either:

```
{% for watchinstance in watchinstance_list %}
    {% ifequal watchinstance.shift "DAY" %}
        <p>shift is DAY</p>
    {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, just calling `{{ watchinstance.shift }}` works as expected:

```
{% for watchinstance in watchinstance_list %}
    {{ watchinstance.shift }}
{% endfor %}
```

returns DAYs and NIGHTs.

I checked whether `watchinstance.shift` returns any extra characters, and it doesn't look like it does... What else can I be missing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A couple of possibilities:

1. The .shift string has extra whitespace.  Use this to double-check:

   ```
   {% for watchinstance in watchinstance_list %}
       X{{ watchinstance.shift }}X
   {% endfor %}
   ```
2. The .shift attribute isn't a string, but an object that stringifies to "DAY" or "NIGHT".  In that case, the variable substitution in `{{ watchinstance.shift }}` would look the same as a string, but the comparison in `{% ifequal watchinstance.shift "DAY" %}` would fail.

Comment: 1) Yup, that's the way I originally checked for extra characters. There were none.

Comment: 2) I was suspecting that had something to do with it! It is indeed a foreign key reference to instance of shift model! After searching for 2 hours I finally found a way to stringify it!

Answer (score 53):

So after searching [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat) for 2 hours, I finally found a way to make it work:

```
{% if watchinstance.shift|stringformat:"s" == "DAY"  %}
```

Comment: I was using the above method and running through the issue of "Could not parse the remainder: '=='IP'' from 'item.status=='IP'' in my case. The issue turned out to be missing spaces before and after the "==". It wont work if you don't have a space before and after the "==". Hope it helps some one.