# Django if statement doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, django

I have the following in my html file:

```
{% trans "Result: "%} {{result}}
```

Which will print out the word SUCCESS on the browser (because thats what the string contains)

But If I do the following:

```
{% if result == 'SUCCESS' %}
   do something
{% else %} 
   do something else
{% endif %}
```

I find that the if statement does not work as expected.

Why is this??

Comment: `repr(result) == "'SUCCESS'"` (e.g. not a different type, no whitespace)?

Comment: A similar question has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3732245/912039).

Answer (score 3):

The `if` statement works fine. Your problem must be regarding the string. Maybe it's not a string at all.

Try the `ifequal` templatetag:

```
{% ifequal result 'SUCCESS' %}
   do something
{% else %} 
   do something else
{% endifequal %}
```

You can try different things. If you're assigning `result` in a view, you can validate it's a string in that very same view:

```
def my_view(request):
    # ... processing ...
    result = something()

    # Let's make sure it's a string containing 'SUCCESS'
    assert type(result) == str
    assert result == 'SUCCESS'
```

You can apply the same logic if it's a context processor.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#ifequal

Answer (score 1):

Check this link:
[Django String format](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat).
according to django documentation you should use this format:

```
{% if result|stringformat:"s" == 'SUCCESS' %}
   do something
{% else %} 
   do something else
{% endif %}
```

or

```
{% if result|stringformat:"s" in 'SUCCESS' %}
       do something
    {% else %} 
       do something else
    {% endif %}
```

or

```
{% ifequal result|stringformat:"s" 'SUCCESS' %}
       do something
    {% else %} 
       do something else
    {% endif %}
```

this problem happen because of your variable type, you should change it to string before compare it to another string.